# The display previous/next command shortcuts doesn't work

Tags: console, zsh

I read in some article that

```
Ctrl+P - to display previous command
Ctrl+N - to display next command
```

But in my terminal it doesn't work. What might be a problem here?
I really would like to display previous/next command right away without using arrow.
And I know about `!!`

UPDATE: I'm under zsh shell, can I have that functionality under zsh shell?

Comment: I guess you are not using bash, maybe your user has a different default shell. Try running `bash`, than runs some commands and test if Ctrl+p works.

Comment: @Letizia, you're right, I'm under zsh shell.

Comment: Try this [how to make ctrl+p behave exactly like up arrow in zsh?](http://superuser.com/questions/583583/how-to-make-ctrlp-behave-exactly-like-up-arrow-in-zsh) or [Separate up arrow lookback for local and global ZSH history](http://superuser.com/questions/446594/separate-up-arrow-lookback-for-local-and-global-zsh-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Letizia, 
I added to ~/.zshrc two lines:

```
bindkey "^P" up-line-or-search
bindkey "^N" down-line-or-search
```